# Generics and LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, linq-to-xml, repository-pattern

I am having a go at creating a generic xmlRepository where I can pass in any type and get a list back.

At the moment my code looks like this (Only way I can get it to work):

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    var filename = GetEntityFileName<TEntity>();
    var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
    var query = (from p in doc.Descendants(entityName)
                 select (ServiceAccount)p).AsQueryable().Cast<TEntity>();
    return query;
}
```

I would like to swap out the

```
select (ServiceAccount)p).AsQueryable().Cast<TEntity>();
```

with

```
select (TEntity)p).AsQueryable();
```

TEntity is the same object as ServiceAccount,

Is this possible with LINQ to XML?

I have a SQLRepository, using EF, which has the same method in it and I am looking for the LINQ to XML equivalent of

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<TEntity>(entityName);
```

If indeed there is one.

Comment: What type of error are you getting when you try your 2nd approach?

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework Code First?

Comment: Cannot convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'TEntity'. 
I have also tried [code] select (typeof(TEntity))p).AsQueryable().OfType<TEntity>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify how you're going to convert an `XElement` to an instance of `T`. Currently your code simply won't work unless `ServiceAccount` already has an explicit conversion from `XElement`.

You may want to have a convention of having a static `FromXElement` method in each entity type - you could then invoke that from reflection, or even have a dictionary:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> Converters =
    new Dictionary<Type, Delegate> {
        { typeof(ServiceAccount),
          (Func<XElement, ServiceAccount>) ServiceAccount.FromXElement },
        { typeof(OtherEntity),
          (Func<XElement, OtherEntity>) OtherEntity.FromXElement },
    };
```

You'd then write something like:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    Delegate converter;
    if (!Converters.TryGetValue(typeof(TEntity), out converter))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
    }
    Func<XElement, TEntity> realConverter = (Func<XElement, TEntity>) converter;

    var filename = GetEntityFileName<TEntity>();
    var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
    return doc.Descendants(entityName)
              .Select(realConverter)
              .AsQueryable();
}
```

It's not really clear why you're using `IQueryable<T>` here, by the way... anything wrong with just `IEnumerable<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

`p` is`XElement`, right?

Then you cast `ServiceAccount` on it. Does it work?

What is signature of this class?

I doubt whether generic constraint `TEntity : class` will work.

Comment: Cast as ServiceAccount does work.

I am thinking that I will just have to implement a switch case of the type and have different linq-to-xml queries